# Adding a string to a dataframe column and create a new column in Python 3.7

Tags: python, pandas

I have following pandas dataframe

```
   col1   col2
0  ORG-1  LOC-100052061, LOC-100032442, LOC-100042003
1  ORG-2  LOC-100005615, LOC-100000912, LOC-100043831
```

I would like to explode col2 and add a url to each value.

The expected output is:

```
   col1   col2              col3                       
0  ORG-1  LOC-100052061     https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100052061
0  ORG-1  LOC-100032442     https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100032442 
0  ORG-1  LOC-100042003     https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100042003
1  ORG-2  LOC-100005615     https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100005615
1  ORG-2  LOC-100000912     https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100000912 
1  ORG-2  LOC-100043831     https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100043831
```

I am trying following lines of code.

```
df_exploded = df.assign(col2=df['col2'].str.split(',')).explode('col2')

url_loc = "https://europa.eu/v1/locations/"
df_exploded['col3'] = 'https://europa.eu/v1/locations/' + df_exploded['col2'].astype(str)
```

But this gives me strange output (only concatenated col3 column is shown).

```
             
                                          col3 
0   https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-10...   
0 https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-1 ...  
0 https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-1 ...  
1   https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-10...   
1   https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-1 ...
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `col1` as the index before you `explode`

```
df_exploded = df.set_index('col1')['col2'].str.split(', ').explode().reset_index()
df_exploded['col3'] = 'https://europa.eu/v1/locations/' + df_exploded['col2']
print(df_exploded)

    col1           col2                                          col3
0  ORG-1  LOC-100052061  https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100052061
1  ORG-1  LOC-100032442  https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100032442
2  ORG-1  LOC-100042003  https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100042003
3  ORG-2  LOC-100005615  https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100005615
4  ORG-2  LOC-100000912  https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100000912
5  ORG-2  LOC-100043831  https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100043831
```

Answer (score 1):

[`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with a lambda:

```
url_loc = "https://europa.eu/v1/locations/"

out = (
 df.assign(col2=df['col2'].str.split(r',\s*'))
   .explode('col2')
   .assign(col3=lambda d: url_loc+d['col2'])
)
```

Output:

```
    col1           col2                                          col3
0  ORG-1  LOC-100052061  https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100052061
0  ORG-1  LOC-100032442  https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100032442
0  ORG-1  LOC-100042003  https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100042003
1  ORG-2  LOC-100005615  https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100005615
1  ORG-2  LOC-100000912  https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100000912
1  ORG-2  LOC-100043831  https://europa.eu/v1/locations/LOC-100043831
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you unaccept the answer? Any issue with it?